# syntax error "unexpected token }" driving me nuts

Tags: javascript, ajax

unexpected token }

I've been through this a thousand times but don't see it.  Have counted open and close curly braces and parentheses, but I'm missing something.

```
function gotoPhotoUploader() {
var db = document.getElementById('dbname').value;
if (db !== 'data') {
  document.location.href="photoUploader.php";
} else {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
data: $('#mysqlIndex'),
url: 'getPageNo.php',
  success: function(data) {
  console_log(data);
  document.location.href="photoUploader.php?&page=" + data;
  }
}
})};
```

What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: Correctly indenting would be a good start.

Comment: I'll indent it for you, and then it should be obvious what the problem is, so @dystroy is spot on, and it should be the answer here.

Comment: You have an extra } in your $.ajax call

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo that would have been noticed with proper indentation.

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/AsThw/ fixed it. This question should not even exist.

Comment: It's not proper to answer the question in the question.

Comment: @ikegami - Not all questions deserve to live and be answered.

Comment: The last line `})};` Should be `});}`

Comment: @adeneo, That's unrelated to what I said and did.

Comment: A text editor that highlights matching brackets wouldn't come amiss too ...

Comment: @dystroy - This sure went downhill fast, does noone read the comments or the posted answers anymore?

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'll remind you the question was about an error.  If the causation was indentation, while not apparent to me, then that is the answer I was looking for, and the help that was needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add brackets, properly space them, and all content inside of them should be indented by one more tab. Doing so will make it really easy to find issues and read the logic of the code.

I'm not sure exactly what parentheses and curly brackets I removed and added, since there were a few changes I have made. I started by just properly formatting the code and the rest just fell into place on where I needed to add the proper closing brackets.

An easy way to format a lot of code that is already incorrectly formatted, is to use the web service [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/). I suggest you don't rely on this service and instead practice good programming techniques. But, there will be cases where you need this if looking at old code, compressed code, or someone else's poorly formatted code.

```
function gotoPhotoUploader() {
    var db = document.getElementById('dbname').value;
    if (db !== 'data') {
        document.location.href="photoUploader.php";
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#mysqlIndex'),
            url: 'getPageNo.php',
            success: function(data) {
                console_log(data);
                document.location.href="photoUploader.php?&page=" + data;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David.  As I explained in an edit, it didn't render on this page the same as in my editor via copy/paste.  Although, I must admit your indentation is better than mine.  My editor (Kate) on the linux side has a mind of its own, and I simply haven't taken time to adjust its settings.  Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention also to the order of your brackets. Namely, you are closing your `else` block before having closed the argument list for `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 1):

yep as Niet pointed out...

```
...}else{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#mysqlIndex'),
        url: 'getPageNo.php',
        success: function (data) {
            console_log(data);
            document.location.href = "photoUploader.php?&page=" + data;
        }
    }
  })
```

should be

```
...}else{
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#mysqlIndex'),
        url: 'getPageNo.php',
        success: function (data) {
            console_log(data);
            document.location.href = "photoUploader.php?&page=" + data;
        }
    });
  }
```